# Can't connect to X after user logs in

Tags: c, linux, service, x11, xserver

I am writing a system service that queries X server information. It is designed a little like this:

```
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
while (1){
    // ... query X for information ...
    sleep(4);
}
```

However, I found that when the user logs in or out, the application terminates with "XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)". I presume this is because X is restarting. I tried to solve this using this code; it keeps trying to connect to X until it succeeds:

```
while (1){
    Display *display;
    while (!(display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
        sleep(2);
    // ... query X for information ...
    sleep(4);
}
```

This code works for when the service first starts up (with system boot). But, after the user logs in, it just hangs in the inner loop, trying to open the X display. Does anyone know how to get the service to connect to X, even when the user logs in/out?

Comment: Don't use GUI features in system (boot-time) daemons, it's a big no-no. Instead you should have a user run the program when the user logs in. You might want to explain *what* you want to do in your daemon, and *why* you want it as a daemon.

Comment: So, the daemon should run regardless of whether a user is logged in. As long as X is running, the daemon should be running too. It periodically checks X server activity, and based on that, sends HTTP requests. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I guess I can run it as a background task when gdm starts (`/etc/gdm/Init`). I'm not sure how to exit the daemon gracefully when X closes, though. Maybe just kill the process in `/etc/gdm/PostSession`?

Comment: Why do you use "while" if there are no windows? How do you meen to filter and handle events? Where are main window? Show more code to help your trouble

Comment: Well, it turns out xlib (which exposes XOpenDisplay) connects to the X server using an authority file from the process owner. Once another user logs in, you need a different authority file to open that user's display. Unfortunately, there's no standard way to get that authority file. I ended up using xcb instead, and searching the Xorg process arguments for the authority file.